# Changing constraints on the fly

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a dijit.form.NumberTextBox input field that starts out with these parms:

```
 new dijit.form.NumberTextBox({
    id: din1,
    style: "width:60px",
    constraints: {
        places: 0,
        pattern: '######'
      }
    },
    din1);
```

Everything works great..My question is I would like to change 'places' and 'pattern' parms on the fly.  So I wrote this to change 'places' and 'patterns' parms:

```
var myFldObj = dijit.byId(din1);
if (myFldObj) {
  var myConstObj = myFldObj.attr('constraints');
  if (myConstObj) {
     myConstObj.places = 2;
     myConstObj.pattern = '#####.0';
  }
}
```

So, after I show the form again, I'd expect the entry field to allow 2 decimal places but the form still acts like places=0 and pattern='######'.  When I check the values of 'places' and 'pattern' I get what I'd expect (2 and #####.0).  My question:

Can you change these values on the fly??

OR

Do you have to destroy the original dijit object and recreate with new parms??

Thx!!

Comment: Additional info: after changing the contraints, when I type a '1.' the input field an invalid message pops up after I type '.'.  But, if I type '1' and tab out of the field, no error message and it formats it as I'd expect '1.00'.  So, is this a bug??? or am I missing something???

Comment: More weirdness: typing '1.0' tab creates the error message when it should just add a zero (1.00).  When I type '1.1' tab it formats it correctly (1.10) - No error msg.  Extremely buggy is seems.....

Comment: The Java number patterns themselves are extremely complicated and not well specified.  I think you need to have a fixed "0" in the whole portion, and if you're setting places manually, why not use "#" in the decimal, like "#####0.###"  Does that work better?

Comment: then you'd only need to change "places" or "pattern", but not both?

Comment: When these parms are changed on the fly, the field doesn't behave the way it should.  See my post below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is what worked for me:

First, I think this is a bug because an input field that starts out like

```
new dijit.form.NumberTextBox({
    id: "fieldID",
    style: "width:60px",
    constraints: {
        places: 0
      }
    },
    "fieldID");
```

that is then changed on the fly with code like:

NOTE: ntbArry - Array of dijit.form.NumberTextBox objs tied to a html
input tag id.

```
for (var x=0;x < ntbArry.length;x++) { 
  var handle = ntbArry[x];
  if (handle) {
    handle.attr('constraints').places = 2;
    handle.attr('constraints').pattern = '#####.0#';      
  } 
}
```

Does not exhibit the same behavior as a field created this way (no constraints mods on the fly):

```
new dijit.form.NumberTextBox({
  id: "fieldID",
  style: "width: 60px",
  constraints: {
    places: 2,
    pattern: '#####.0#'
  }
},
"fieldID");
```

It's close in behavior but every time you type a decimal point, the error message pops up stating invalid entry.  This message doesn't pop up when typing the decimal point on a field that was originally created with the constraints places=2 and pattern '#####.0#'.

So, to get original behavior I wanted:

fieldIDEvents is an array of dojo events tied to NumberTextBox fields.
Before continuing disconnect dojo events

```
for (var x=0;x < fieldIDEvents.length;x++) {
  var handle = fieldIDEvents[x];
  if (handle) {    
    dojo.disconnect(handle);
  }
}
```

then destroy the NumberTextBox dojo objects

```
for (var x=0;x < ntbArry.length;x++) {
  var handle = ntbArry[x];
  if (handle) {
    handle.destroy();
    ntbArry[x] = null;
  }
}
```

Next, place the input tag back into the html because it gets destroyed:

NOTE: tdtag and an id on a html td tag which should contain the input tag.

```
var fld1 = this.document.getElementById("tdtag");

if (fld1) {
  //alert("\""+fld1.innerHTML+"\"");
  fld1.innerHTML = "<input id=\"fieldID\">";
}
```

Now, create the NumberTextBox object again:

```
ntbArry[0] = new dijit.form.NumberTextBox({
  id: "fieldID",
  style: "width: 60px",
  constraints: {
    places: 2,
    pattern: '#####.0#'
  }
},
"fieldID");
```

It's a few extra steps but, at least I know this is what works for me..If I'm missing something basic, let me know, it's easy to miss the small details with this stuff.

Comment: you should file a report at bugs.dojotoolkit.org.

Comment: I will file a bug report for this.  I forgot to mention that I was using 1.3.2 and just upgraded yesterday to 1.4.2 and I still see the same behavior.  Also, I modified the constaints to use only 'pattern: '#####.00' without setting the 'places' property.  So, the bug is easily created by starting with a NumberTextBox with pattern '#####' and then changing the pattern to '#####.00' on the fly (No 'places' needed).

Answer (score 0):

I use Dojo 1.3 and I can see that dijit.form.NumberTextBox has no `pattern` and `places` properties, but has `editOptions` property. So I would try to change the constraints like this:

```
myConstObj.editOption.places = 2;
```

Comment: pattern and places are found on the constraints object, itself a property of NumberTextBox.  editOptions is protected and is only for formatting the value while it is actively being edited