# show future date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, dojo

I want to show the future date and time in the date and time field components.

Below is the sample code:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/parser"
], function(lang, registry, ready) {
    ready(function() {
        var time = registry.byId("time");
        time.set("constraints", lang.mixin(time.get("constraints"), {
            min: 'T08:00:00' 
        }));
    });
});
```

In the above code **min** constraint is used to disable time before 8:00AM , but i want to disable the past time and if user selects future date the time should not disable.Please suggest. Thanks.

--EDITED--
jsp page:

```
Date<input type="hidden" name="userDate" value="${myDTO.USER_DATE}"/> <input name="USER_DATE" id="oracle" value="${myDTO.USER_DATE}" required="true"/>
Time: <input type="hidden" name="userTime" value="${myDTO.USER_TIME}"/> <input id="time" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" onChange="require(['dojo/dom'], function(dom){dom.byId('val').value=dom.byId('time1').value.toString().replace(/.*1970\s(\S+).*/,'T$1')})"
             data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss', clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00', visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00', visibleRange: 'T01:00:00' }" />
```

js:

```
require(["dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TimeTextBox){

       function showTimeValue(){
            try{
            dom.byId('val').value = document.getElementsByName('time')[0].value;
            }catch(err){}
        }
       new TimeTextBox({
           name: "time",
           value: document.getElementsByName('userTime')[0].value,
           onChange: function(v){ setTimeout(showTimeValue, 0);},
            constraints: {
                timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss',
                clickableIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
                visibleIncrement: 'T00:15:00',
                visibleRange: 'T01:00:00'
            }
        }, "time").startup();
       showTimeValue();
    }); 
// for Dynamic date value
  //code for Date field
  // ....
  new OracleDateTextBox({
                value: document.getElementsByName('userDate')[0].value,
                name: "oracle",
                required: true,
                onChange: function(v){ ...}
```

Comment: Nothing here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/TimeTextBox.html ?

Comment: @mplungjan - please understand my question, i already done disabling the past date in date dropdown , pls chck the fiddle in above post. Looking to disable past time based on date selected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561963/changing-constraints-on-the-fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by accessing your time element inside the onchange callback of your DateTextBox. You will need to inject all the time widget dependencies into your second require statement. When the date changes, check if it is today and otherwise allow the user to select all time slots.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/1/

```
onChange: function(v){ 
                var useMin, now, time, pad;
                pad = function(n) {
                  n = n + '';
                  return n.length >= 2 ? n : new Array(2 - n.length + 1).join('0') + n;
                }
                useMin = 'T00:00:00';
                now = new Date();
                if ((now.getDate() === v.getDate()) &&
                    (now.getYear() === v.getYear()) &&
                    (now.getMonth() === v.getMonth())
                    ){
                    var hour = pad(now.getHours());
                    var minute = pad(now.getMinutes());
                    useMin = 'T' + hour + ':' + minute + ':00';
                } 
                time = registry.byId("time");
                time.set("constraints", lang.mixin(time.get("constraints"), {
                    min: useMin 
                }));
                setTimeout(showServerValue, 0);
            }
```

Comment: By why we have to give useMin = 'T08:00:00' as it only allows disabling time before 8:00AM, what if current time is 3:00PM and i want to disable time before 3:00PM. Please suggest

Comment: Good point, I've updated the fiddle to provide you with a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but the issue is i need to show the current date in the text box when user goes to the web page similarly i want to show the dynamic value(user selected value when he create the stage) in the date field when user edits the webpage, but when i'm trying to show the value in the datefield the functionality is not working, i need to pick other date and choose current date if i want to see disabled values in the timetextbox , any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks. @chriskelly

Comment: I've created a new fiddle for you which sets the initial date values. HTH ... http://jsfiddle.net/eurochriskelly/8o23tbLu/4/

Comment: Sorry to bother you, when user goes to edit Stage screen i want to show dynamic date and time values in the fields which i retrieve from database ,which user have selected in create Stage screen , for that i have used value: document.getElementsByName('userDate')[0].value in my js code. please see the same code in jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/6. currently your code is displaying current date even in Edit Stage screen. –@chriskelly

Comment: No bother! I just use the current date but you can replace it with those dates you have stored in your hidden inputs very easily. Can you show me in what format have you stored those dates and I will update the fiddle. Then you can test.

Comment: Time Format: T23:15:00 , date Format : 22-Aug-2014 , these are dynamic values format which i'm getting from my controller class but i will display then using document.getElementsByName('userDate')[0].value. Please see above post edited for more information , thanks @chriskelly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59829/discussion-between-chriskelly-and-user3684675).

Comment: oh.. no worries. what i said was try this : http://jsfiddle.net/eurochriskelly/8o23tbLu/5/

Comment: unable to disable past time in firefox and IE .when open the URL for the first time, to disable the past time we need to modify the date field to some other date and again select today's date.Please check the http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/7/ in IE or firefox. Where as in chrome it works for the first time when we open the URL. Please suggest.Thanks.@chriskelly

Comment: Seems to be related to locale. Take a look at this link and see if it helps: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dojo_date/. Perhaps using dojo/date will help but first, what is your locale? I typically only ever have to worry about 'en-gb' or 'en-us'.